# putextra coloca dados na memoria RAM

Tags: android

`putextra` coloca dados na RAM?

Eu tenho que fazer `getIntent().removeExtra("nome")` para apagar o conteúdo?

Comment: Não entendi a finalidade da sua pergunta. Pode explicar o porquê da sua dúvida?

Comment: eu gostaria de saber até quando os dados de putextra ficam disponiveis. é até a proxima activity que eu chamar?

Comment: Os dados ficam disponíveis enquanto a instância do *Intent* estiver disponível. Edite a pergunta e junte um exemplo de código que exemplifique a sua dúvida.

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível apagar esse conteúdo.

**Durante a existência dessa atividade, o Intent necessáriamente existirá na memória para que você tenha informação de como essa atividade foi chamada e como ela existe.** Um `Intent` é uma "mensagem" que inicializa um processo, uma atividade.

Além disso, o método `getIntent()` pegaria uma cópia do intent original, você não estaria alterando o intent que foi usado, e sim uma cópia dele e removendo os extras dessa cópia. Então, se você desse `getIntent()` novamente, você estaria fazendo outra cópia do original que teria novamente os extras.

O tipo de dado que você passa pelo `Intent` geralmente tem tamanho muito pequeno, portanto não há muita necessidade de tentar remover eles. Afinal, se você passou pra outra atividade eles têm valor importante pra atividade. Muito provavelmente, se o pause ou stop forem chamados durante a execução (tela bloqueada, foi pra tela inicial e voltou, etc), esse extra seria necessário novamente na recriação da atividade.